# Grab ticker codes and company name from Bloomberg [r]

Tags: r, bloomberg, back-testing

I have grabbed ticker codes for the S&P500 using `HistIndexTickers("SPX", startdate="19980101", freq="MONTHLY")` in the RbbgExtension package

How can I get the company name using the corresponding ticker codes? (Some companies have been acquired or ticker has been delisted etc. but I still would like to have the company name as I am backtesting)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
HistIndexTickers(index = "SPX", field = "ticker", startdate="19980101", freq="MONTHLY")
```